# How to save input file files to electron?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, electron

I'm developing a program using electron, but now I'm in a dilemma,

how can I save the file sent by the input file into the "uploads" folder that is located at the root of my program?

this is my form.

```js
new: function() {
  var b = $('body');
  var local = b.find('select#local').val();
  var nome = b.find('input#nome').val();
  var img = b.find('input#img');

  if (nome.length && local.length && img.length) {
    var db = new sqlite3.Database('./sabores.db');
    db.each("SELECT cidade_id FROM locais WHERE local_id = ?", [local], (err, row) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        db.run("INSERT INTO pratos (local_id, prato_nome, prato_img, cidade_id) VALUES ('" + local + "', '" + nome + "', '" + img + "', '" + row.cidade_id + "')", [], (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            jetpack.readAsync(img.val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "")).then((data) => {
              console.log(data);
            });
            // admin.page('pratos');
          }
        });
      }
    })

    db.close();
  } else {
    modal.erro('Todos os campos são obrigatórios');
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit="prato.new(); return false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="local">Local</label>
      <select id="local" class="form-control" required>
        <option>Selecione um local...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="nome">Nome</label>
      <input type="text" require class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Prato Gostoso">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="img">Imagem</label>
    <input type="file" require class="form-control" name="img" id="img" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block float-right mb-5">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide more context as to your setup and goals. As it stands, it's difficult to tell what the files are, etc.

Comment: this question is right, but when you ask a question in stack overflow you have to follow some rules. if you put some code you tried it will help to understand the issue and the answers also. hope you get what i am saying.

Comment: Thanks, i posted my code in the next answer

Comment: for saving the data into file in File System , use node fs module . keep in mind for renderer process set the nodeIntegration option to true while creating window in main process.